# Change desktop version page to different styling for mobile version

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time to figure this out. Currently, as you can see below, I have links that are below the image.

I would like those links, when the user is on their mobile version of the site, to be below the content rather then the image.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The following is the html of the page. The css I am using is from bootstrap:

```html
<div class="row">
     <aside class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <span class="editableObject editableComponent" style="display: block; width: 181px; float: none;"><span class="editableObjectContents" style="display: block; width: 181px; float: none;">
   <p><img alt="About Us" height="220" src="/assets/Image/about-us.jpg" width="220"></p></span>
   <ul class="editableObjectControl">
    <li class="edit"><a href="/admin/?muraAction=cArch.edit&amp;contenthistid=4F3181C1-155D-0201-110389B72699E8CC&amp;siteid=Regal-en-us&amp;contentid=FB628EF2-155D-0201-11F363089D9B2CE8&amp;topid=00000000000000000000000000000000001&amp;type=Component&amp;moduleid=00000000000000000000000000000000003&amp;parentid=00000000000000000000000000000000003&amp;compactDisplay=true&amp;homeID=80EAE971-155D-0201-113C16061274FBBA" data-configurator="false" title="Edit" class="frontEndToolsModal"></a></li>
   </ul>
   </span><nav id="navStandard" class="mura-nav-standard well">
   <ul class="nav nav-list">
  
  <li class="first"><a href="/index.cfm/about-us/our-awards/">Our Awards</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/index.cfm/about-us/compliance-and-resources/">Compliance and Resources</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/index.cfm/about-us/our-contracted-hospitals/">Our Contracted Hospitals</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/index.cfm/about-us/our-health-plans/">Our Health Plans</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/index.cfm/about-us/our-leaders/">Our Leaders</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/index.cfm/about-us/our-mission-and-history/">Our Mission and History</a></li> 
  <li class="last"><a href="/index.cfm/about-us/our-organization-and-offices/">Our Organization and Offices</a></li> </ul> </nav>
     </aside><!-- /.span -->
     <section class="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 content">
      <nav class="hidden-xs"><ol itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" id="crumblist" class="mura-breadcrumb breadcrumb breadcrumb">
     <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="first"><a itemprop="item" href="/"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="1"></li><li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="last"><a itemprop="item" href="/index.cfm/about-us/"><span itemprop="name">About Us</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="1"></li>
    </ol></nav> 
      <h1 class="pageTitle"><div class="mura-editable inactive inline">
      <label class="mura-editable-label">TITLE</label>
      <div contenteditable="false" id="mura-editable-attribute-title" class="inactive mura-editable-attribute inline" data-attribute="title" data-type="text" data-required="true" data-message="" data-label="title">About Us</div>
      </div></h1>
     <div class="mura-editable inactive">
       <label class="mura-editable-label">BODY</label>
       <div contenteditable="false" id="mura-editable-attribute-body" class="inactive mura-editable-attribute" data-attribute="body" data-type="htmlEditor" data-required="false" data-message="" data-label="body"><p>Group has been providing quality, innovative healthcare to&nbsp;Los Angeles, Riverside, San Bernardino, Ventura and Orange Counties&nbsp;for more than 35 years.&nbsp; With the largest physician-owned network in Southern California, more than half a million people and their families have selected us to deliver their healthcare.</p>

<p>We have doctors in your community who speak your language and understand your culture. As a result of the high quality of care our doctors provide, we are a 4.5 STAR network as measured by the Centers for Medicare &amp; Medicaid Services.</p>

<p>At Regal Medical Group, we take a whole-health approach to help our patients improve physical, mental, and emotional well-being. We do this by offering value-added services like patient focused programs, health education classes, health fairs, and more!</p></div>
       </div> 
     </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sharing your current HTML and CSS will greatly improve your chances of receiving helpful answers.

Comment: Also just phones, or tablets too? Basically you need a media query in your CSS to change the layout depending on device or screen size.

Comment: @PatrickMoore the html has been uploaded

Comment: @JosephSanatar and I am aware to use media query and I have tried but it isnt responding. It will overlap with the body content

Answer (score 0):

A very quickly, but non-elegant, way to solve this is to print the link section twice... one inside a `visible-xs`, the other inside a `hidden-xs`...

```
<div class="visible-xs">I am the same menu but visible only when extra small devices</div>
<div class="hidden-xs">I am the same menu but hidden only when extra small devices</div>
```

your posted code isn't clear, but I assume you're using `twitter bootstrap`.

Comment: Yes I am and I would use this the styling in hidden-xs and just rearrange the items?